# Gradle not excluding specified file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-eclipse

I have added `exclude` statement but still my exclude `abc/object/MyTestConfig*.class` are getting added in jar, any reason why ?

```
jar {
  zip64 true

  from((configurations.compile - configurations.jarDepends).collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  }
  from ("$projectDir/src/main/java/") {
    include "**/*.hbm.xml", 
            "abc/tools/xml/XMLClasses.MF"
    exclude "abc/object/MyTestConfig*.class"
  }
}

task filterVersionConstants(type: Copy) {
  from "src/main/java/abc/"
  into "src/main/java/abc/"
  include "VersionConstants.tmpl"
  exclude "**/MyTestConfig*.class"
  rename { String fileName -> 
      fileName.replace('.tmpl', '.java')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of trial and error, finally I'm able to exclude this file from my jar as below. Basically I need to pull exclude statement in `jar` task at first.

```
jar {
  zip64 true
  exclude "abc/object/MyTestConfig*.class"

  from((configurations.compile - configurations.jarDepends).collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }) {
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
  }
  from ("$projectDir/src/main/java/") {
    include "**/*.hbm.xml", 
            "abc/tools/xml/XMLClasses.MF"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to exclude a class file from the source directory, but only your Java(source) files reside there. Are you trying to prevent the class from being built, or just not packaged? Exclude the java file to prevent it from being built, or exclude the class file from the output directory and not the source directory.

Comment: by any mean I want this class shouldn't be a part of this jar